# Add a form inside an accordion

Tags: html, forms, css, accordion

I am currently using the accordion I found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/).

Here is the CSS:

```
        .ac-container{
            width: 400px;
            margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
        }

        .ac-container label{
            font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 20;
            display: block;
            height: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #777;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            line-height: 33px;
            font-size: 19px;
            background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
            box-shadow:
                0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3),
                1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset,
                0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F7F5;
        }

        .ac-container label:hover{
            background: #fff;
        }

        .ac-container input:checked + label,
        .ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
            background: #c6e1ec;
            color: #3d7489;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
            box-shadow:
                0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3),
                0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }

        .ac-container label:hover:after,
        .ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            right: 13px;
            top: 7px;
            background: transparent url(../images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center; 
        }

        .ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
            background-image: url(../images/arrow_up.png);
        }

        .ac-container input{
            display: none;
        }

        .ac-container article{
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            margin-top: -1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 0px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 10;
            transition:
                height 0.3s ease-in-out,
                box-shadow 0.6s linear;
        }
        .ac-container input:checked ~ article{
            transition:
                height 0.5s ease-in-out,
                box-shadow 0.1s linear;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
        }

        .ac-container article p{
            font-style: italic;
            color: #777;
            line-height: 23px;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 20px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        }

        .ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
            height: 440px;
        }
        .ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
            height: 180px;
        }
        .ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
            height: 230px;
        }
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
        <section class="ac-container">      
            <div>
                <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="ac-1">Available options </label>
                <article class="ac-small">
                <form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">
                    <div align="center"><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese
                    </div>
                </form>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div><!--...--></div>
        </section>
```

Unfortunatly, I can't see the radio button inside the accordion (when I drop down the "Available options") but I can see the items. Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: you probably don't see the checkbox either since you defined your inputs to not display on the css where you have .ac-container input{display: none;}

Comment: If my answer was the answer you were looking for, please mark it as accepted by clicking the outlined checkmark just to the left of this answer's contents, at the top. That will show to others that this question has been answered, and in case others might end up on this page it'll also show them that this answer was what you were looking for. If this was not the answer you needed, you can add a comment explaining what is still not working right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the CSS3 accordion uses the dynamic `:checked` pseudo-class on a checkbox input. Clicking on an "accordion header" toggles that checkbox's checked state, and that then toggles the styles on the accordion's content. To remove the checkboxes though, the accordion has the following style:

```
.ac-container input {
    display: none;
}
```

This also inherits to the inputs in your form. You can solve this by just overriding that style:

```
.ac-container form input {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the css completly before asking, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say you'd have to check everything in the imported/copied css actually, but if something goes wrong, you could check if there are any interfering styles. You can also check for that in the dev tools in Chrome, by pressing F12 or right clicking the element (or an element close to it) and selecting "Inspect Element". In the menu that then shows up, navigate through the elements you see until you've selected the element you want to see the styles for, and then check to the right to see what styles appy to it.